# How to check if a cell in my imported data contains 0 html python

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

Trying to check if any of the values in my imported CSV file contain 0

I know hoe to check and see if it contains any null values

```
steam_data.isnull().sum()
```

Which prints out

```
name                0
release_date        0
english             0
developer           0
publisher           0
platforms           0
required_age        0
categories          0
genres              0
steamspy_tags       0
achievements        0
positive_ratings    0
negative_ratings    0
average_playtime    0
median_playtime     0
owners              0
price               0
```

but don't know how to getting the sum of columns that contain 0.
Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: The sum of columns that contains 0 is always 0, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
(steam_data == 0).sum()
```

seemed to do the trick, i don't think I asked this question properly apologies

output:

```
name                    0
release_date            0
english               511
developer               0
publisher               0
platforms               0
required_age        26479
categories              0
genres                  0
steamspy_tags           0
achievements        11864
positive_ratings      667
negative_ratings     2906
average_playtime    20905
median_playtime     20905
owners                  0
price                2560
```